# Computing a conditional probability using a martingle

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, martingales, stopping-times

Suppose that $S_n$ is a symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ and $a,b$ are some integers. Moreover, let $\tau$ be the first time the walk arrives to $b$ or $-a$. I would like to compute the expected value of $\tau$ given that we arrived to $b$ before we arrived to $-a$.

I started by assigning a random variable $\tau_c$ for every integer $c$ where:

$$\tau_c =\min\{n|S_n=c\}$$

Now, we get that $\tau=\min\{\tau_b,\tau_{-a}\}$. Moreover:

$$E[\tau\ |\ \tau_{b}<\tau_{-a}]=\frac{E[\tau\cdot1_{\{\tau_{b}<\tau_{-a}\}}]}{P(\tau_{b}<\tau_{-a})}$$

Using the martingale $S_n$ and *Doob's optimal stopping theorem*, I found out that:

$$P(\tau_b<\tau_a)=\frac{a}{a+b}$$

However, I can't go any further than that... I was told to consider the martingale $M_n=S_n^3-3nS_n$.

Hints will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[Presumably $a>0$.]

The martingale $M$ is a good choice!

As a start, it's well known that $E[\tau] = ab$.
Momentarily abbreviate $q=P[\tau_b<\tau_{-a}]=a/(a+b)$ and $k=E[\tau\cdot 1_{\{\tau_b<\tau_{-a}\}}]$. Then, by Optional Stopping,
$$
0=E[M_\tau] = -a^3(1-q)+b^3q-3bk+3a(ab-k).
$$

Comment: Can you explain the computation of $E[M_T]$ a bit more?

Comment: I can try (hope I got it right!): On the event $\{\tau_{-a}<\tau_b\}$ you have $M_\tau=-a^3+3a\tau$; on the event $\{\tau_{b}<\tau_{-a}\}$ you have $M_\tau=b^3-3b\tau$. Therefore
$$
\eqalign{
E[M_\tau]
&=E[M_\tau; \tau_{-a}<\tau_b]+E[M_\tau; \tau_{b}<\tau_{-a}]\cr
&=E[-a^3+3a\tau; \tau_{-a}<\tau_b]+E[ b^3-3b\tau;\tau_{b}<\tau_{-a}]\cr
&=-a^3P[\tau_{-a}<\tau_b]+3aE[\tau; \tau_{-a}<\tau_b]+b^3P[\tau_{b}<\tau_{-a}]-3bE[\tau;\tau_{b}<\tau_{-a}]\cr
&=-a^3(1-q)+3a(ab-k)+b^3q-3bk.\cr
}
$$
(Upon typing this out I found a sign error in my original answer — now fixed.)